# How to do in place increments in VBA when cell contains specified text?

Tags: vba, for-loop, if-statement, ms-word

I am trying to loop through the rows in column four of a table.

If the cell in the row has the text "Yes", I want to add 1 to X which I initiated as 0 at the start of the code.

My code does not increment and returns a zero or any other value that I initiate X to be.

```vb
Sub Row_Iter()

    Dim otable As Table
    Set otable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim Col As Integer
    Col = 4
    Dim x As Integer
    
    ''Section 1

    With otable.Columns(Col)
        x = 0
        For Row = 4 To Row = 7
            If otable.Cell(Row, Col).Range.Text = "Yes" Then
                x = x + 1
            End If
        Next Row
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why aren't you using countif.

Comment: @freeflow - probably because the OP isn't using Excel

Comment: Ah.  You just get so used tto excel related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

The first is that `For Row = 4 To Row = 7` should be `For Row = 4 To 7`

The second is that `If otable.Cells(Row, Col).Range.Text = "Yes"` will never evaluate to True. This is because each cell contains a non-printing end of cell marker which consists of two characters. You can see this quite clearly by checking the length of an empty cell in the Immediate window, e.g.

`?len(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1,1).Range.Text)`

So, your code should be:

```
Sub Row_Iter()

Dim otable As Table
Set otable = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Col As Integer
Col = 4
Dim x As Integer

    x = 0
    For Row = 4 To 7
        If left(otable.Cell(Row, Col).Range.Text, 3) = "Yes" Then
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next Row

End Sub
```